# Rename detection with whitespace ignored in git merge

Tags: git

I've got a git repo where almost every file needs to be renamed, and undergo a transformation that makes substantive changes to ~5% of lines, but changes the leading whitespace of almost every line.

I did this in two commits. In the first commit I renamed every file from the old filename to the new filename, but didn't do any other changes. In the second commit I applied the transformation to the contents.

Now I'd like to be able to merge in a branch from before the transformation. It kinda seems like something like this would work:

`git merge foo-branch -s recursive -Xignore-all-space -Xpatience`

But it looks like `-Xignore-all-space` does not apply to the rename detection, so I get output like:

`CONFLICT (modify/delete): old-filename.js deleted in HEAD and modified in foo-branch. Version foo-branch of old-filename.js left in tree.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To merge the transformation, do it in at least two steps:

```
$ git checkout mybranch
$ git merge <the-rename-commit>
[deal with any issues here and commit if the merge failed]
$ git merge <commit-after-rename>
```

For particularly tricky or difficult cases, you will want *three* steps:

```
$ git checkout mybranch
$ git merge <commit-just-before-mass-rename>
[deal with any issues here and commit if the merge failed]
$ git merge <the-rename-commit>
$ git merge <commit-after-rename>
```

The idea here is to take care of everything *before* (and maybe including) the rename, then take care of the rename (only), then take care of everything *after* the rename.

(In your case you'll want to run all three steps with the `-X` flag on at least the first and last.  It probably will make no difference for the middle step.)

Note that Git version 2.18 has a new feature: when it detects mass renaming of files within some higher level directory, it will rename newly added files the same way.  See [the release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.18.0.txt) for (not much) detail.  If your Git predates 2.18, or the feature misfires, you may want to do the merge of the rename itself with `--no-commit` so that you can fix up pathnames before committing manually.